# Sql to Slick Conversion

Tags: mysql, sql, database, slick, dsl

I am converting SQL queries to slick DSL. I am stuck in timestamp conversion.
My SQL query is:

```
Select isActive from users where create_time <= TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE,
${AUTO_EXPIRY_DB_DAYS * HOURS_24 * MINUTES_60}, sysdate())
and isVerified=false;
```

How to write a slick query for the same?

```
userQuery.filter(user => user.isVerified === FALSE && user.createdDate
<= ?????).map(_.isActive)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at scalar database functions [slick documentation](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.3/userdefined.html#scalar-database-functions). I suppose this should work:

```
val sysdate = SimpleLiteral[java.sql.Timestamp]("sysdate")
val timestampAdd = SimpleFunction.ternary[String, Int, java.sql.Timestamp, java.sql.Timestamp]("TIMESTAMPADD")

userQuery
    .filter(user => user.isVerified === FALSE 
                && user.createdDate <= timestampAdd("MINUTE", 20, sysdate))
    .map(_.isActive)
```